# Django Rest Framework - Group data by dynamic Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to format data when querying my API. I can retrieve my data like that :

```
"results": [
        {
            "Cat1": [
                {
                    "job": String,
                    "position": Integer
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Cat1": [
                {
                    "job": String,
                    "position": Integer
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Cat2": [
                {
                    "job": String,
                    "position": Integer
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

But I want something like that:

```
"results": [
        {
            "Cat1": [
                {
                    "job": String,
                    "position": Integer
                },
                {
                    "job": String,
                    "position": Integer
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Cat2": [
                {
                    "job": String,
                    "position": Integer
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I use a serializer like this:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CatSerializer()
    job = JobSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            value.category.name: [{"job": value.job.name,
                                 "position": value.position, }]
```

cat1 and cat2 are dynamics, they are from another table. I don't understand how to create my arrays properly using those serializers. The category is a `@Property` field in my model who's a foreign key of job.

My models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(4)]

    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)

    @property
    def category(self):
        return self.job.category.domain


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s | position: %s' % (self.partner.name, self.domain.name, self.job.name, self.position)
```

```
class Job(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255)
```

```
class Category(models.Model):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hourly_rate = models.FloatField(
        null=True, blank=True)
```

How should I deal with serializers to format my data properly ?

EDIT:

I ended with something like that, except for the ListSerializer.

I used 2 ModelSerilizers

```
class MyModelCustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    position = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    job = serializers.CharField(source='job.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['job', 'position']

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {"position": value.position,
                "job": {"name": value.job.name, "slug": value.job.slug, 
             "title": value.job.seo_title}
                }
```

And

```
class CategoryCustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    models = MyModelustomerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['category', 'MyModel']

    def to_representation(self, value):

        filters = {'job__category__domain__name': value.name}

        myModels = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters)
        serializer = MyModelCustomSerializer(instance=myModels, many=True,)

        return {value.name: serializer.data}
```

But if I try to use a jobSerializer who already exist instead of

`"job": {"name": value.job.name, "slug": value.job.slug, 
            "title": value.job.seo_title}
                }`,

I got this error: Object of type 'Job' is not JSON serializable, but it's working anyway because i don't need all fields

Comment: please show your models or at least the relationships between them (MyModel, Category and Job). But your serialiser is for MyModel, so obviously it's returning a list of MyModel instances.

Comment: You should probably start with the Category serializer, with nested relationship to the positions, because you want to end up with a list of categories (not positions).

Answer (score 0):

I would go the direction of implementing a custom [ListSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) for the ModelSerializer and overriding its `to_representation` method.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from collections import OrderedDict

class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        list_rep = OrderedDict()

        for item in iterable:
            child_rep = self.child.to_representation(item)
            k, v = list(child_rep.items()).pop()
            list_rep.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

        return [
            {k: v} 
            for k, v in list_rep.items()
        ]
```

Then set the model Meta to use it

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CatSerializer()
    job = JobSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = CustomListSerializer

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {
            value.category.name: [{"job": value.job.name,
                                 "position": value.position, }]
```

Comment: I ended with a code like this except for the ListSerializer